# React not displaying the data fetched from MongoDB using Node/Express JS

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm pretty new to the MERN stack and recently tried creating a database and fetching the data from one of the collections on my database. When I tried to fetch the collections in my database, it shows them correctly without any error. However, when I try to fetch the data inside a specific collection, the data is not being displayed at all. In the console log it shows an array of length 0.

Here is my code:

App.tsx:

```
// App.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  const [admin, setadmin] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4001/getAdmin') // Update the endpoint to fetch admin
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data); // Log the data fetched from the API
        setadmin(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);

  if (loading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
  if (error) return <div>Error: {error}</div>;

  return (
    <div className='mt-10 ml-10'>
      <table className='border border-black px-10 py-10'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Password</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {admin.map(admindata => (
            <tr key={admindata._id}> {/* Assuming _id is the unique identifier */}
              <td>{admindata.username}</td>
              <td>{admindata.password}</td>
              <td>{admindata.name}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js(Server side):

```
// index.js

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const AdminInfoModel = require('./models/AdminInfoModel');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const PORT = 4001;

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/MESAA")
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Error connecting to MongoDB:', err));

app.get('/getAdmin', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const adminData = await AdminInfoModel.find();
        res.json(adminData);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

AdminInfoModel.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const AdminInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // Use ObjectId type for id field
        username: String,
        password: String,
        name: String
    }
);

const AdminInfoModel = mongoose.model('AdminInfo', AdminInfoSchema);

module.exports = AdminInfoModel;
```

Comment: why did you call  app.get inside mongoose connect ?

Comment: What is the name of your collection? Based on your model name of `AdminInfo` mongoose will look for a collection named `admininfos`. @Nasir the `app.get` is not inside the mongoose.connect.

Comment: did you get the response from calling GET api in `console.log` line ?

Comment: Also, refer [Mongoose Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#compiling) about how the collection name is derived.